# How to work from my computer on branch located on development server, with Git?

Tags: git

First, a bit of context.
I work for a consulting company, working with PHP, that has it's own Gitlab repo and a dev server, which can either be at the office or on whichever customer's own servers.
Each employee have their own directory on the dev server web root with a clone of the repo. Makes it easier for supervisors/bosses to see or show progress done.

Most of my coworkers use vi, or even text editors with a ssh plugin, so they just connect through SSH and work directly on the server. But I personally use IDEs. Some IDEs work well with SSH, but some don't. The main issue lies where I don't only publish, I need to sync my local files, whenever i pull on my branch on the dev server.

So, my question is: Can I work, from my computer, on my branch on the dev server, using git, without having to create a whole branch(without needing to do the whole checkout/commit/push/pull stuff) on my computer?

I have seen questions around here that are close to my issue, but none are really it, and I've been Googling around a bit, without finding exactly what i need, so I ask here.

PS: Sorry if I am not quite clear or anything, I am very well known t-o be incompatible with clarity and efficiency in my questions...

Comment: What’s your question exactly? Are you looking for an IDE that supports SSH connections? One that does the push/pull dance for you?

Comment: Do you understand what a branch _is_ in git? You can work locally just fine without a server, but as soon as you want to share that work you'll need the "whole checkout/commit/push/pull stuff".

Comment: @evolutionxbox If I understand correctly, OP doesn’t want to work locally but rather work through SSH on a `git` repo on a distant server. That repo is itself a clone of the main version that’s on their company’s Gitlab. I don’t understand why they don’t work locally, but that’s not the question.

Comment: @bfontaine yeah. It shouldn't matter, as long as the repo is cloned, the process is identical.

Comment: @bfontaine, I [can] have an IDE that can work through SSH. The issue is the dance.
No clue why the company needs that intermediary copy, well, i know, but it doesn't quite make sense in a subversioning context. But that's how I'm supposed to work.
I would just like to not have my own local clone then have to push from my local copy to the server's copy, for demonstration purposes or whatever, then push to the base repo when ready to deploy.
But, I'm guessing that's not possible. Either work directly on the dev server, dance around with the middleman or push directly to gitlab. My guess.

Comment: @ravenwish1990 Yeah I think you’re guessing right :)